# Why doesn't waitpid wait for the process to exit?

Tags: linux, perl, waitpid

In the below script I am trying to figure out how `waitpid` works, but it doesn't wait for `ssh` process to exit. `done` is printed right away and not after the `ssh` process exists.

**Question**

How to I make `waitpid` only continue when the pid I give it have exited?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);
my $pid = $pm->start;
my $p = $pid;
if (!$pid) {
    system("ssh 10.10.47.47 sleep 10");
    $pm->finish;
}

$p = qx(/usr/bin/pgrep -P $p);
print "ssh pid is $p\n";

my $kid;
do {
    $kid = waitpid($p, 0);
} while $kid > 0;

print "done\n";
```

I have also tried

```
while (1) {
    $p = kill 0, $p;
    print "x";
    sleep 1 if $p;
    print "*";
    last unless $p;
}
```

but it doesn't even reach the first `print` for some reason and never exits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `wait` family of functions only work on child processes, even `waitpid`.  The sleep process is not your child, it's your child's child.  This is because `system` is essentially `fork` + `exec`.  By using Parallel::ForkManager + system you're forking, then forking again, then executing sleep.

Since you've already forked, you should use exec.  This has the extra advantage of not needing the call to pgrep and it's timing problem (ie. it's possible the parent will call pgrep before the child has executed system).

```
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);
my $pid = $pm->start;
my $p = $pid;
if (!$pid) {
    no warnings;  # no warnings "exec" is not working
    exec("sleep 10");
    $pm->finish;
}

print "sleep pid is $p\n";
waitpid($p, 0);
```

For simplicity it's now using sleep.  A warning from Perl that "Statement unlikely to be reached" must be suppressed because Perl doesn't realize `$pm->start` has forked.  This should be `no warnings "exec"` but that's not working so I had to suppress them all.